# What is the main reason of using “DAG” instead of “blockchain-based”?

Tags: blockchain, directed-acyclic-graphs

Some of DLTs (Distributed Ledger Technologies) such as [IOTA](http://iotatoken.com/IOTA_Whitepaper.pdf) or [SPECTRE](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/1159.pdf) use **DAG** (**Directed Acyclic Graph**) contrary to many DLTs such as Bitcoin, Ethereum, Hyperledger etc that use blockchain-based structure.

Question :

1. **Why these DLTs preferred to use DAG instead of blockchain-based structure ?**
2. **How DAG structure can help us to improve problematics of blockchain-based DLTs ?**

Answer (score 1):

A DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph, which flows in one direction, branches, and has no cycles) is more flexible than a traditional blockchain (which is a DAG with no branches--just a line with points).  For example, a source control mechanism with multiple forks can be implemented with a DAG DLT, but not a simple blockchain--or not very easily at least.

Comment: Thank you, Could you please give me an example about _"source control mechanism with multiple forks"_ to understand better what does it mean? Thanks

Comment: Use Google or other search engine for "git dag".  Here's an example, of many:
https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application_development/9781782168454/1/ch01lvl1sec11/viewing-the-dag

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem surrounding the conventional DLT's is the transaction charge.

IOTA has tried to remove this problem by removing miners from their network or more formally **the role of miners and transaction issuers are now played by everyone in the network.**  I won't explain IOTA here. (check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivWqqfzunhI) for more details).

First, I will try to list out the benefits:

- No transaction fees
- Less computation required. (You can use your mobile phone for submitting a transaction)

If we use a weak cryptographic proof then any normal device will be able to compute it in seconds or minutes and the whole network will be flooded with **valid blocks**, waiting to be attached to the DLT. If we have only one point in the DLT (as in conventional blockchains), then due to the presence of many **valid blocks**, the network will never be able to reach a consensus.

Instead, what they do is they have a DAG as the DLT and so, there are different points where new blocks can be attached.

You might be wondering that since they don't use hard cryptographic proofs, then how double spending is averted. Here, the sheer volume of transactions helps in preventing double spending.

If you are interested to know how they do it (in detail), check this [paper](https://assets.ctfassets.net/r1dr6vzfxhev/2t4uxvsIqk0EUau6g2sw0g/45eae33637ca92f85dd9f4a3a218e1ec/iota1_4_3.pdf) out.